# Rational Inequality Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Is my process correct?

Solve: $\dfrac{x-3}{x+5}\leq3$

$$\dfrac{x-3}{x+5}-\dfrac{3(x+5)}{x+5}\leq0$$

$$\dfrac{x-3-3x-15}{x+5}\leq0$$

$$\dfrac{-2(x+9)}{x+5}\leq0$$

$$\dfrac{x+9}{x+5}\geq0$$

Points on number line are $-9$ with a closed interval, $-5$ with an open interval.

Upon plotting, I have concluded the solution to be:

$$\boxed{(-\infty,-9]\cup(-5,\infty)}$$

Comment: Your final answer looks right, but the intermediate work has a typo--the inequality should become "$\geq$" when you divide it by $-2$, right?

Comment: Woops, yes that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Going from line 3 to line 4, you've made a tiny mistake.

Remember, that when we multiply (or divide) an inequality by a negative number, we reverse the direction of the inequality, so it should be

> $\dfrac{(x+9)}{x+5}\color{green}{\geq}0$.

Other than that, your final solution is, indeed, correct.

Remember: if in doubt, ask Wolfram Alpha!

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x-3%29%2F%28x%2B5%29+%3C%3D3

Comment: Forgot about Wolfram, however wolfram doesn't write most answers in Interval Notation which I am just starting to learn which is one reason why I asked here as so I could confirm I wrote it correct.